# How to speed up AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, caching

I have a custom AJAX survey script. I want to improve the efficiency of how it handles information  to really speed it up for my users. The CSS needed to style subsequent AJAX  view is located in the website's main CSS  as it shares many similar selectors, and is cached on load using..

```
<FilesMatch "(?i)^.*\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
Header set Last-Modified "Tue, 31 Aug 2010 00:00:00 GMT"
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2014 20:00:00 GMT"
Header set Cache-Control "public, no-transform"
</FilesMatch>
```

Will AJAX use this cached information to reduce round trip request time?

Html markup for each subsequent AJAX view is different so I understand that info would have to be fetched, parsed, and returned.  If setting caching headers can't do the job, seems some client side scripting could be directed to check cache for information first, if it needs more information then go get it from server (such as html markup.)

Any help would be appreciated. Hope you can set me on the right path here.

Comment: AJAX requests shouldn't load the page resources, so the AJAX request wouldn't be sped up by caching.

Comment: So can caching be done with client side javascript?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense in the context of a typical ajax request.  A typical ajax request is to fetch some `data` from the server that the client doesn't already have (thus there's nothing to cache).  What exactly you are retrieving with ajax?  We can't help you figure out how to speed it up if we don't know what you're loading.  CSS files will typically be cached by the browser automatically (in the memory/disk cache) so I don't know why you're trying to change that.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok, CSS is my primary concern. If cached by the browser means AJAX doesn't fetch CSS request from server for all subsequent pages then I'm good. I thought AJAX requested and parse CSS from server for each subsequent AJAX pages viewed. Thanks.

Comment: Jay, as I've already said we cannot help you until you tell us what you're loading with Ajax.  Usually Ajax is used to get some data that javascript puts into the page or used to execute some sort of command on the server.  What are you actually loading with ajax and what client-side library are you using for the ajax call?  There should be no CSS loaded as part of a normal ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those directives won't affect a PHP script being requested via AJAX. One thing you should do is cache the output of the script being requested. I really like this method:

http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/output-caching-for-beginners/